# Filter data received from an API call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I separate the data received from an API call and store it in a reducer?

My API call:

**ACTION:**

```
export function fetchCatsFromAPI() {
  return(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getCats())
     fetch(myapi)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(getCatsSuccess(json)))     // <= Dispatching the entire data.
    .then(json => dispatch(getCatsTotalSuccess(json.total)))  // <= This did not work.
    .catch(err => dispatch(getCategoriesFailure(err)))
  }
}


getCategories() : Dispatches FETCHING_CATEGORIES
getCategoriesSuccess() : Dispatches FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS
getCategoriesFailure() : Dispatches FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE
```

The API call returns:

```
{"total":6,"categories":[{"id_cat":1,"name":"CAT01"},{"id_cat":2,"name":"CAT02"}]}
```

**REDUCER:**

```
const initialState = {
  categories: [],
  totalResults: '',
  isAdding: false,
  error: {}
}

export default function categories(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCHING_CATEGORIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: true
      }
    case "FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        categories: action.data,
        totalResults: action.data.total // <= This did not work.
      }
    case "FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        error: action.err
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

Having another case for `getCatsTotalSuccess` also doesn't work for `json.total`

I want to have a separate `var` for `categories` and `total`. How do I do this?

**UPDATE 1: ACTIONS:**

```
function getCats(){
  return {
    type:FETCHING_CATEGORIES
  }
}

function getCatsSuccess(data){
  return {
    type:FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    data
  }
}

function getCatsTotalSuccess(data){
  return {
    type:FETCHING_CATEGORIES_TOTAL_SUCCESS,
    data
  }
}

function getCatsFailure(err){
  return {
    type:FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
    err
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `getCatsTotalSuccess` action creator implementation?

Comment: Updated the question with `UPDATE1` Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dispath`, inside your action, to code in the most followed convention in React, you need to send an object of two properties: **type**  and **payload**. The `payload` will contain the data which your API returned and the `type` will be a reference to which `reducer` to update

You did not show what your action creators code contained, so instead, I am writing what should be a working version of your code. Including the action creators.

Here is how you action code should look:

```
import { 
    FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    FETCHING_CATEGORIES,
    FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE 
    } from 'constant-path'

export function fetchCatsFromAPI() {
  return(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES}) // We tell our store that we are iniaiting an API call. This is ideal to since network calls may take several MS to load. A spinner can be rendered while we are at this stage
     fetch(myapi)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => dispatch({ type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, payload: json))     // <= I believe here was your mistake 
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE, payload: err}))
  }
}
```

How your reducer should look:

```
import { 
FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
FETCHING_CATEGORIES,
FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE 
} from 'constant-path' 

const initialState = {
  categories: [],
  totalResults: '',
  isAdding: false,
  error: {}
}

export default function categories(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCHING_CATEGORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: true
      }
    case FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...payload
      }
    case FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        error: action.err
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

Constant file would look like:

```
export const FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS = 'FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS';
export const FETCHING_CATEGORIES = 'FETCHING_CATEGORIES';
export const FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE = 'FETCHING_CATEGORIES_FAILURE';
```

With the above, you'd be secured from an annoying and common problem which developers encounter when they don't use constants when dispatching from actions towards the reducers.

Comment: Updated the question with `UPDATE1` Please check.

Comment: alright, Check my reducer code now underneath the action's code. I think what you had wrong is objects mapping. If this still does not work, we can take this into a chat and I am sure we can get it sorted in a short time. It seems a small issue that we are missing

Comment: if you do a console.log(action.payload) under ```case FETCHING_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:```, in my code, you should see the API data. If you don't see that and you are sure you following each stepped I instructed you, let me know

Comment: The `console.log` doesnt work at all. Does not return anything. How can we start the chat please?

Comment: We can start the chat here and  when SOF realise we are having a chat, it will ask us if we would like to take this into a chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155150/discussion-between-matthew-barbara-and-somename).